# Lablgtk2 Installation on Windows

Tags: editor, ocaml

I am currently relearning Ocaml and am in the need of a good editor. There is a new editor from OcamlForge: OCamlEditor http://ocamleditor.forge.ocamlcore.org/. Prerequisite for installation is Lablgtk2.

Installing Lablgtk2 on windows is not straight forward and there is good instruction here: http://wwwfun.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/soft/lsl/install-win32.txt

I have completed the first two steps and in the third step, as warned, it is failing on the native code version. This is where I am left stranded. How do I check to see if the assembler is on my path? What am I missing here?

Please help me move forward from this point.

Comment: I have the same problem too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an MSVC installation, right? By default MSVC doesn't add command-line tools (`cl` - compiler, `ml` - assembler, `link` - linker) to the [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (and needed directories to `INCLUDE` and `LIB`). But it provides a shell script to do this - `MSVS9\Commnot7\Tools\vsvars32.bat`. Copy it somewhere to the `PATH` so that you can easily call it any time needed. Then, before running ocaml compiler call `vsvars32.bat` to setup the environment. You can make this environment permanent by looking at changes to %INCLUDE%, %LIB% and %PATH% variables made by this script and adding them manually to environment variables of current user (usual windows gui insanity - My Computer -> Additional -> Environment variables).